# Curious about UnixBench results, is my HD configured properly?

Tags: hard-drive, performance

I downloaded UnixBench 5.1.3 and ran it on both my old Dell 4600 and my newer Gateway SX2800.  With a 2.4Ghz P4 the Dell gets clobbered on cpu tests by the Gateway with quad core Q8200 at 2.3GHz.

The surprising thing is that the old Dell with a Maxtor STM3200820A (ATA) drive is much faster than the newer Gateway with a WDC WD6400AAKS-22A7B2 (SATA) on file tests.  For example:

File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks:

```
 181258.6 (Dell, Centos 6.5)
 16985.0 (Gateway, Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS)
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! I believe your results should be in the format of baseline/result/index. Posting the hdparm output from dell as well and the full output of the **File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks test** from both systems would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I added "hdparm -Tt" results which go the "right" way and the full UnixBench results that go the "wrong" way.  Perhaps this is just a UnixBench problem (or bug?).  If there is a config change I should do to my Ubuntu system I certainly will though.

Comment: As embarrassing as it is, self-solved above.

Comment: Don't be embarrased! Self solving is encouraged here. Write it up as an answer. Your experience will likely be valuable to someone else in the same situation. Drop a comment with @ElderGeek when your done and I'll upvote it which will help your rep.

Comment: no worries on the upvote.  i hope this does help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured this out.  This is the "encrypted home directory" tax.

I re-ran the test on my notebook, in and out of my encrypted home, and got these results:

Encrypted home:

```
   BYTE UNIX Benchmarks (Version 5.1.3)

   System: thx2219: GNU/Linux
   OS: GNU/Linux -- 3.5.0-48-generic -- #72~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 20:08:23 UTC 2014
   Machine: i686 (i386)
   Language: en_US.utf8 (charmap="UTF-8", collate="UTF-8")
   CPU 0: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5270 @ 1.40GHz (2793.2 bogomips)
          Hyper-Threading, x86-64, MMX, Physical Address Ext, SYSENTER/SYSEXIT
   CPU 1: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5270 @ 1.40GHz (2793.2 bogomips)
          Hyper-Threading, x86-64, MMX, Physical Address Ext, SYSENTER/SYSEXIT
   09:23:29 up 6 min,  2 users,  load average: 1.90, 0.99, 0.42; runlevel 2

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark Run: Fri Jun 20 2014 09:23:29 - 09:51:35
2 CPUs in system; running 1 parallel copy of tests

Dhrystone 2 using register variables        8748168.4 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Double-Precision Whetstone                     1670.2 MWIPS (10.1 s, 7 samples)
Execl Throughput                                956.3 lps   (29.8 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks         11428.0 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 256 bufsize 500 maxblocks            2883.5 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 4096 bufsize 8000 maxblocks         43587.0 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
Pipe Throughput                              438447.2 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Pipe-based Context Switching                  22667.8 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Process Creation                               2913.5 lps   (30.0 s, 2 samples)
Shell Scripts (1 concurrent)                   2979.9 lpm   (60.0 s, 2 samples)
Shell Scripts (8 concurrent)                    666.9 lpm   (60.1 s, 2 samples)
System Call Overhead                         911599.9 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)

System Benchmarks Index Values               BASELINE       RESULT    INDEX
Dhrystone 2 using register variables         116700.0    8748168.4    749.6
Double-Precision Whetstone                       55.0       1670.2    303.7
Execl Throughput                                 43.0        956.3    222.4
File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks          3960.0      11428.0     28.9
File Copy 256 bufsize 500 maxblocks            1655.0       2883.5     17.4
File Copy 4096 bufsize 8000 maxblocks          5800.0      43587.0     75.1
Pipe Throughput                               12440.0     438447.2    352.4
Pipe-based Context Switching                   4000.0      22667.8     56.7
Process Creation                                126.0       2913.5    231.2
Shell Scripts (1 concurrent)                     42.4       2979.9    702.8
Shell Scripts (8 concurrent)                      6.0        666.9   1111.5
System Call Overhead                          15000.0     911599.9    607.7
                                                                   ========
System Benchmarks Index Score                                         200.4

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark Run: Fri Jun 20 2014 09:51:35 - 10:19:56
2 CPUs in system; running 2 parallel copies of tests

Dhrystone 2 using register variables       14400540.8 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Double-Precision Whetstone                     2977.2 MWIPS (10.2 s, 7 samples)
Execl Throughput                               3468.0 lps   (29.8 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks         10015.0 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 256 bufsize 500 maxblocks            2525.0 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 4096 bufsize 8000 maxblocks         38482.5 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
Pipe Throughput                              774637.1 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Pipe-based Context Switching                 181309.2 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Process Creation                              10315.5 lps   (30.0 s, 2 samples)
Shell Scripts (1 concurrent)                   5067.0 lpm   (60.0 s, 2 samples)
Shell Scripts (8 concurrent)                    670.5 lpm   (60.1 s, 2 samples)
System Call Overhead                        1551102.1 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)

System Benchmarks Index Values               BASELINE       RESULT    INDEX
Dhrystone 2 using register variables         116700.0   14400540.8   1234.0
Double-Precision Whetstone                       55.0       2977.2    541.3
Execl Throughput                                 43.0       3468.0    806.5
File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks          3960.0      10015.0     25.3
File Copy 256 bufsize 500 maxblocks            1655.0       2525.0     15.3
File Copy 4096 bufsize 8000 maxblocks          5800.0      38482.5     66.3
Pipe Throughput                               12440.0     774637.1    622.7
Pipe-based Context Switching                   4000.0     181309.2    453.3
Process Creation                                126.0      10315.5    818.7
Shell Scripts (1 concurrent)                     42.4       5067.0   1195.0
Shell Scripts (8 concurrent)                      6.0        670.5   1117.4
System Call Overhead                          15000.0    1551102.1   1034.1
                                                                   ========
System Benchmarks Index Score                                         357.8
```

Unencrypted dir:

```
   BYTE UNIX Benchmarks (Version 5.1.3)

   System: thx2219: GNU/Linux
   OS: GNU/Linux -- 3.5.0-51-generic -- #77~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 5 00:47:34 UTC 2014
   Machine: i686 (i386)
   Language: en_US.utf8 (charmap="UTF-8", collate="UTF-8")
   CPU 0: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5270 @ 1.40GHz (2792.8 bogomips)
          Hyper-Threading, x86-64, MMX, Physical Address Ext, SYSENTER/SYSEXIT
   CPU 1: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5270 @ 1.40GHz (2792.8 bogomips)
          Hyper-Threading, x86-64, MMX, Physical Address Ext, SYSENTER/SYSEXIT
   13:02:27 up 7 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.50, 0.31, 0.17; runlevel 2

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark Run: Fri Jun 20 2014 13:02:27 - 13:30:28
2 CPUs in system; running 1 parallel copy of tests

Dhrystone 2 using register variables        8578638.6 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Double-Precision Whetstone                     1671.1 MWIPS (10.2 s, 7 samples)
Execl Throughput                                962.5 lps   (29.9 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks        261941.5 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 256 bufsize 500 maxblocks           80624.9 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 4096 bufsize 8000 maxblocks        613075.2 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
Pipe Throughput                              437733.6 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Pipe-based Context Switching                  21707.5 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Process Creation                               2925.7 lps   (30.0 s, 2 samples)
Shell Scripts (1 concurrent)                   3287.6 lpm   (60.0 s, 2 samples)
Shell Scripts (8 concurrent)                    735.4 lpm   (60.0 s, 2 samples)
System Call Overhead                         911615.6 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)

System Benchmarks Index Values               BASELINE       RESULT    INDEX
Dhrystone 2 using register variables         116700.0    8578638.6    735.1
Double-Precision Whetstone                       55.0       1671.1    303.8
Execl Throughput                                 43.0        962.5    223.8
File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks          3960.0     261941.5    661.5
File Copy 256 bufsize 500 maxblocks            1655.0      80624.9    487.2
File Copy 4096 bufsize 8000 maxblocks          5800.0     613075.2   1057.0
Pipe Throughput                               12440.0     437733.6    351.9
Pipe-based Context Switching                   4000.0      21707.5     54.3
Process Creation                                126.0       2925.7    232.2
Shell Scripts (1 concurrent)                     42.4       3287.6    775.4
Shell Scripts (8 concurrent)                      6.0        735.4   1225.6
System Call Overhead                          15000.0     911615.6    607.7
                                                                   ========
System Benchmarks Index Score                                         433.1

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark Run: Fri Jun 20 2014 13:30:28 - 13:58:32
2 CPUs in system; running 2 parallel copies of tests

Dhrystone 2 using register variables       15140050.1 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Double-Precision Whetstone                     2976.3 MWIPS (10.2 s, 7 samples)
Execl Throughput                               3485.0 lps   (29.9 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks        386644.8 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 256 bufsize 500 maxblocks          119772.7 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
File Copy 4096 bufsize 8000 maxblocks        859500.6 KBps  (30.0 s, 2 samples)
Pipe Throughput                              785277.0 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Pipe-based Context Switching                 180743.2 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)
Process Creation                              10408.1 lps   (30.0 s, 2 samples)
Shell Scripts (1 concurrent)                   5567.7 lpm   (60.0 s, 2 samples)
Shell Scripts (8 concurrent)                    743.1 lpm   (60.1 s, 2 samples)
System Call Overhead                        1549181.8 lps   (10.0 s, 7 samples)

System Benchmarks Index Values               BASELINE       RESULT    INDEX
Dhrystone 2 using register variables         116700.0   15140050.1   1297.3
Double-Precision Whetstone                       55.0       2976.3    541.1
Execl Throughput                                 43.0       3485.0    810.5
File Copy 1024 bufsize 2000 maxblocks          3960.0     386644.8    976.4
File Copy 256 bufsize 500 maxblocks            1655.0     119772.7    723.7
File Copy 4096 bufsize 8000 maxblocks          5800.0     859500.6   1481.9
Pipe Throughput                               12440.0     785277.0    631.3
Pipe-based Context Switching                   4000.0     180743.2    451.9
Process Creation                                126.0      10408.1    826.0
Shell Scripts (1 concurrent)                     42.4       5567.7   1313.1
Shell Scripts (8 concurrent)                      6.0        743.1   1238.6
System Call Overhead                          15000.0    1549181.8   1032.8
                                                                   ========
System Benchmarks Index Score                                         886.6
```

The moral of the story for me is that while encrypted homes are good, remember not to use them for disk intensive tasks, especially those not requiring security.